# Is $R[X]$ a necessarily UFD for $X$ an infinite set of symbols?

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

Let $R$ denote a UFD, and let $X = \{x_0,\cdots,x_{n-1}\}$ denote a finite set of symbols. Then $R[X]$ is a UFD. This follows, since if $R$ is a UFD, then so too is $R[x],$ for any symbol $x \notin R$.

> **Q.** If $R$ is a UFD, and $X$ is an arbitrary set, possibly infinite, is $R[X]$ necessarily a UFD?

Comment: Note that any particular polynomial involves only finitely many $x_i$'s, so yes, it is a UFD.

Comment: @hardmath: I don't think that this is enough. Because this argument indicates that any directed colimit of UFDs is an UFD. But why should prime elements in the rings should stay prime in the colimit? We really have to use the special setting (see also Bill's answer).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: We do need "the special setting", but with a domain $R$ it is clear that no factor of a polynomial in $x_0,\ldots,x_{n-1}$ can entail other indeterminates.  Bill's Answer highlights this observation and puts it in a nice context, and I've upvoted it.  Still, the essence of my Comment is that any factoring in $R[X]$ takes place in a UFD, so if UFDness were going to fail, it would fail already in a finite number of indeterminates.

Comment: Yes, OK, but one has to be really careful to which ring the terms "factor", "prime element", "irreducible element" etc. belong. As I've said, your argument "sounds" as if any directed colimit of UFDs is UFD, but this is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Key Idea** $ $ Each successive polynomial ring extension $\,D\subset D[x]\,$ is factorization **inert**, i.e. the ring extension introduces no new factorizations, i.e. if $\, 0\ne d\ \in D\,$ factors in $\,D[x]\,$ as $\,d = ab\,$ for $\, a,b\in D[x]\,$ then $\,a,b\in D.\,$ From this one easily deduces that the requisite factorization properties extend to the ascending union $\,R[x_1,x_2,\cdots\,].$  The same ideas works for arbitrary inert extensions.

**Remark** $\ $ Paul Cohn introduced the idea of inert extensions when studying Bezout rings. Cohn proved that every gcd domain can be inertly embedded in a Bezout domain, and every UFD can be inertly embedded in a PID. There are a few variations on the notion of  inertness that prove useful when studying the relationship between factorizations in base and extension rings, e.g. a weaker form where $\, d = ab\,\Rightarrow\, au, b/u\in D,\,$ for some unit $\,u\,$ in the extension ring.