# What properties of $R$ does the monoid ring $R[M]$ inherit?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, monoid

It's known that polynomial rings $R[x_1,...,x_n]$ inherit some properties of a base ring $R$. For example, (due to the [wikipedia article on polynomial rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring)) if $R$ is an integral domain, then so is $R[x_1,...,x_n]$ and if $R$ is a UFD, then so is $R[x_1,...,x_n]$.

General monoid rings are generalizations of the notion of a polynomial rings in finitely many variables. For example, if $X$ is an infinite set, then we can form a "polynomial ring" in $|X|$ many variables as $R[M]$ where $M$ is the free commutative monoid on $X$. Of course, if $X = \{x_1,...,x_n\}$, then this construction yields a usual polynomial ring $R[x_1,...,x_n]$. On the other hand, $R[M]$ is a free algebra on $X$ for the free (non-commutative) monoid $M$ on $X$.

My question is: what properties of $R$ are preserved by $R[M]$ for a monoid $M$? For instance, is being an integral domain is preserved? I would also like some references on the matter.

Comment: Does an abelian monoid which is free on $\{x_i \mid i\in I\}$ necessarily isomorphic to $\oplus_{i\in I}\mathbb N$?  I ask because I'm not completely certain: I don't know what dangers lie for intuition outside free abelian groups. If it is, then it seems like the same proof as for polynomial rings would hold.

Comment: @rschwieb: yes.

Comment: The only thing I can think of that is preserved is that if $M$ is finitely generated and abelian, then $R[M]$ is Noetherian iff $R$ is, by Hilbert's basis theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, being an integral domain is not preserved; for example, if $M$ is the free idempotent (the free monoid on an element $m$ satisfying $m^2 = m$) then $R[M] \cong R[m]/(m^2 - m) \cong R \times R$. I don't know anything useful to say about what is preserved. The monoid ring construction is very general.

Comment: What about the case when $M$ is the free monoid on an infinite set $X$ ($R[M]$ then being a polynomial ring in infinitely many variables)?

Comment: @Jxt921: assuming you mean "free commutative monoid," then as you say, $R[M]$ is a polynomial ring, and is an integral domain and a UFD if $R$ is (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1266784/is-a-polynomial-ring-over-a-ufd-in-countably-many-variables-a-ufd).